# data-ng-controller does not work after an update to angularjs 1.2.0

Tags: angularjs

I updated my project from angular 1.0.8 to 1.2.0 and something as simple as this  not work for me:

```
<div data-ng-include="'partial1.html'" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

How can I use the variables from MainCtrl scope in partial1.html??

This example works fine using angular version 1.8.0:[example1](http://plnkr.co/edit/RUTCfkYsl5J7DkzGD5Dp?p=preview)

But this, using version 1.2.0 does not work: [example2](http://plnkr.co/edit/n6nbSZZ2t8cUIuzJ47mw)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627) in 1.2 which causes `ng-include` to fail when used with other directives.

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-include="'partial1.html'"></div>
</div>
```